# Rename modem in HylaFAX reusing the existing configuration

Tags: linux

I'm running HylaFAX 6.0.6 on Raspbian Stretch with an USR5637 U.S. Robotics USB modem. The configuration was created with faxsetup and faxaddmodem for `/dev/ttyACM0`.

The modem is connected to an USB hub that sometimes temporarily disconnects. HylaFAX does not recover from the interruption because the new device file is named `/dev/ttyACM1`. (I guess it gets created while `/dev/ttyACM0` still exists.)

I have written a udev rule that creates a symbolic link `/dev/ttyUSR5637` to whatever the modem device's name is. How can I "rename" the modem in the HylaFax configuration and reuse as much as possible of the existing configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be easier than I thought. Here is what I did:

1. Stop HylaFAX service
2. In `/etc/hylafax`, rename `config.ttyACM0` to `config.ttyUSR5637`
3. In `/var/spool/hylafax`, remove all files with `ttyACM0` in their names
4. Start HylaFAX service